# Full screen WPF App To act as operating system

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, security, touchscreen

I realize this might sound a little dubious but I assure you it isn't. I have a client who wants a win 8 pro touch screen app. One of the requirements is that the app is the only thing on the device the user may use. So my question is, can I make it so that the user cannot exit my wpf application? I have it running full screen without toolbars but they could still click on start etc. I essentially want it to run on windows but kind of be its own OS. Any advice is appreciated. Also if this is something that can be handled in group policies or some other way I would love to have that advice as well. Thank you.

Comment: You thank people by clicking the up-triangles to the left of each answer. If one of the answers solved your problem, click the check-mark icon to the left of the answer.

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to set Windows 8.1 to run in "Kiosk" mode.

[How to enable Kiosk mode in Windows 8.1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/hyperyash/archive/2013/10/25/enable-kiosk-mode-in-windows-8-1.aspx)

The only caveat, is that the app must be a Windows modern app, not WPF.

> Windows 8.1 comes with an excellent feature where you can lockdown the
>   device allowing the user to use only one application. You need to keep
>   in mind that this application needs to be a modern application and
>   cannot be a desktop application. So, if you are going to use it for
>   your customized company application (For e.g. ATMs, Flight Schedule),
>   the application should be a modern application

Answer (score 0):

There is a product called "Secure Lockdown" from Inteset http://shop.inteset.com/lock-down-windows-7-with-inteset-secure-lockdown that looks like it can be used with a WPF app. I've not used it (yet), but it looks like it should work for your scenario. It's not free, but it reasonably priced at around $20. It says it is compatible with Windows 8 as well.